# IE10 CSS3 Animation Speed not dynamically updating with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, animation, internet-explorer-10, css-animations

This is part of a larger side-project I am working on. I have a series of moving divs, using @keyframes and CSS3's animation property. After much difficulty getting this working in webkit browsers due to issues with transform3d and opting to use left: and top: etc. instead, I was finally getting somewhere. I had faster/slower buttons which changed the seconds property, specifying the animation speed inline. This works fine in Chrome but not in IE.

http://jsfiddle.net/AxQQB/6/ (EDIT: infinite looping animation now)

As you can see, I can set the initial animation style inline like this:

```
var speed = 1.5;
var animationCSS = 'myfirst '+speed+'s';


$('#button1').click(function () {
alert("Set initial speed");

$('#test')
.css('background-color', '#000')
.css('animation', animationCSS);
.css('-webkit-animation', animationCSS); 
});
```

I am therefore using jQuery to dynamically assign the animation CSS with a custom speed. I have a second button to change the speed variable and reassign the CSS. The animation should then happen again as a new inline style has been applied. This works fine in chrome but not IE10 :( I have a separate removeCss function which seems to be working fine, it works in Chrome with or without this line anyway.

```
$('#button2').click(function () {
    alert("Slow down and change speed");
    %('#test').removeCss('animation,-webkit-animation,
    speed = 10;
    animationCSS = 'myfirst '+speed+'s';
    $('#test').css('background-color', '#00FFFF')
        .css('animation', animationCSS)
       .css('-webkit-animation', animationCSS);
});
```

It's driving me mad, if I inspect the elements I can see the new speed variable has been applied inline, however there is no visible change. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

By my understanding the animation will only reply if you change `animation-name` to a different value. The easiest way to do this would be to attach an `animationEnd` event to the element, and set `this.style.animationName = "";` in that handler. Then, when you assign the new animation to it, it will play correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) In my main project, the animation is constantly happening, set to infinite, and I'm changing the speed of it as it's still moving. I am guessing an animationEnd event then wouldn't be applicable in this case? Sorry for the confusion, here is a jsfiddle with the infinite animation: http://jsfiddle.net/AxQQB/6/

I have also added the line which removes the animationName and unfortunately I've had no joy with that :(

Answer (score 0):

Create an animation named `mysecond` that has the same keyframes, and alternate the animation names between myfirst and mysecond when you want to update the speed.  This should trigger the animation to update.  Alternatively, create a few classes for your different animations that have different animation names in addition to the speed and set the appropriate class.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AxQQB/11/

if you want a smooth transition between them, you should catch the animationiteration event, and change the class at that time.